# How to use Chrome Extension Api with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension, I have a "`background.js`" which it filters the url and fetchs data from my api. When the conditions is meet I am sending a message from "`background.js`". And I want to catch it from `Angular component`.

**background.js**

```
...
chrome.pageAction.show(tab.id, () => {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({data: dataFromAPI})
        });
...
```

I ran `npm install --save @types/chrome`.

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {chrome} from '@types/chrome';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( data => console.log(data));
  }

}
```

But WebStorm says, "`.../node_modules/@types/chrome/index.d.ts' is not a module.` "

**How can I use Chrome Api from Angular Component?**

Comment: chrome.pageAction.show only exposes the icon, it doesn't open the pageAction itself so those scripts aren't running and you can't send messages there. Only when the user clicks the icon, the pageAction popup is shown and can receive messages.

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend any solition to activate the pageAction and send data it from the background.js, also the main problem is "ng build" is not working.Error :"ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(11,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'chrome'."

Comment: did you get the solution for this? Same problem here

Answer (score 4):

```
/// <reference types="chrome"/>
import {chrome} from '@types/chrome';
// Remove chrome import
```

IMPORTANT: Must add three slashes before reference.

If still it doesn't work then add "Chrome" in tsconfig.json types.

```
compilerOptions: ["types": [ "Chrome" ] ]
```

Comment: Here can we remove chrome import and keep just ///<ref... line only ?

Comment: @mayurkukadiya yes. Check the answer again. It's mentioned.

Comment: If I remove import statement, then it  is give me an error chrome is not define..

Comment: I am actually finding  solution for chrome type not support in Iphone and iOS devices. So asking...

Comment: In compilerOptions, you have to add 'chrome' in types. And add refrence in your file(s).

Answer (score 4):

Add the line

```
///<reference types="chrome"/>
```

to the very top of your TS file (preferably line 1). (DO NOT OMIT THE 3 SLASHES IN THE BEGINNING)

Also run the command

```
npm install --save @types/chrome
```

Things will start working after that.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed `npm install --save @types/chrome`

so file stop showing an error `Cannot find name 'chrome' when build`

then I'm trying to build the library by using the command `ng build` but it was broken because it didn't find a chrome so what I did?

I added this line `///<reference types="chrome"/>` on top of file `public-api.ts`

Note: Must add three slashes(///) before reference.

Comment: What if we want to use chrome API in angular project. not in angular library.
I have no any public-api.ts file.