# How to use chrome extension in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

How can i use chrome in my angular app?In my app.module

```
export const CHROME = new InjectionToken('CHROME');
```

and

```
providers: [...{ provide: CHROME, useValue: window.chrome } ...],
```

In my service

```
/// <reference types="chrome"/>
import { chrome } from '@types/chrome';
```

```
constructor(  @Inject(CHROME) private chrome: chrome) {
  }
```

But i have an error:

> TS2306: File
>   'C:/Users/Sergey/Desktop/someProject/node_modules/@types/chrome/index.d.ts'
>   is not a module. TS6137: Cannot import type declaration files.
>   Consider importing 'chrome' instead of '@types/chrome'.

Comment: Looks like this question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53169721/how-to-use-chrome-extension-api-with-angular

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know how right it's, but it helped me: add .d.ts file in which 'declare let chrome'.